# How to avoid android res created by build: values-b+sr+Latn

Tags: android, gradle

How can I determine why Android is creating a bad resource directory? Gradle fails with:

```
6:47:17.175 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'C:\libl\Android\sdk\build-tools\1.1.0\aapt.exe'' finished with exit value 1 (state: FAILED)
6:47:17.180 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] invalid resource directory name:
C:\dev\appdir\build\intermediates\res\merged\dev\debug/values-b+sr+Latn
```

**debug/values-b+sr+Latn** Where is that coming from?  We have no res in our project. Its just values and values-sw720p type stuff. I clearly see this folder created by Android:

```
\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\mediarouter-v7\24.0.0\res\values-b+sr+Latn
```

and

```
\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.1\res\values-b+sr+Latn
```

Two problems here. Why is Android doing this and how do I stop it? How to fix Android appcompat and mediarouter to work on Windows?

Note, changes were made to go from this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
```

to this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

Comment: So, reverted to not use the newer libraries for now. Appears they are not compatible with Windows. Due to corporate security, no longer allowed to develop on Mac or Linux.

Comment: I am very interested in how did you come to this conclusion ? It looks really immature to accept this.

Comment: To the core of the problem i see that by the documentation there is no way for a folder name to contain "+" since every other values folder names are separated with "-".
If someone is more knowledgeable would be good to point out what causes these folders to be recreated every time we build a project.

Comment: I am able to create a directory with + in the name and MSDN seems to say it is valid. So, maybe its the forward slash? **merged\dev\debug/values-b+sr+Latn**